# Sonatype Nexus 3 - Scripting Docker Image Cleanup?

Tags: docker, groovy, nexus, sonatype

I am looking to create a Groovy script to use as a Nexus 3 Task operation which will clear out my docker proxy repo on a weekly basis. I am not sure of the API or how to get access to the com.sonatype.nexus.plugins libraries/source/docs in order to learn how to accomplish this. It appears I would need to use the com.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-repository-docker:3.0.2-02 package, but that it not available from Maven Central. Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!